# Sum value in array with pervious values and place it in new matrix

Tags: matlab

I have an array like [1 ; 2 ; 3; 4; 5].
I want to sum every value with previous vales and make a new array like this:
[1 ;3 ;6 ;10 ;15]
The real matrix is bigger than this and contains more than 2000 value.

Comment: `sum([[a1] [0 ;a1(1:end-1)]],2)`

Comment: which is faster?
cumsum or this?

Comment: Not sure, why not benchmark it for yourself?

Comment: @Divakar: That code produces a different result.

Comment: @Cena Could you check back your results? Should it be ` [1 ;3 ;6 ;10 ;15]`?

Comment: @Divakar it produces this:
b =

     1
     3
     5
     7
     9

Comment: @Cena Ah right, gotch ya! `cumsum` is the man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [cumsum](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) function.

Comment: Is it fast enough?
or if i write a loop it calculate faster?

Comment: @Cena: Try it out, use `profile` or `tic` `toc`. I'm pretty sure cumsum is faster.

Comment: Tnx. cumsum is better now I compared it with loop.